# How to mock array of class using Mockito

Tags: java, mockito, testng

I want to mock Order array class  Order[].class.  below mockMapper reads Order[].class and need to return Order[].class.

Service class

```
public class OrdersConnectorImpl {
    public Order getOrderById(String Id, OrderType orderType) throws Exception {

        Response response = null;
        response = orderServiceTarget.queryParam("ID", Id).queryParam(ORDER_TYPE, orderType).request().accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .get();
        final StatusType responseStatus = response.getStatusInfo();
        final String serverResponseStr = response.readEntity(String.class);
        if (responseStatus.equals(Response.Status.OK)) {
            objectMapper = getObjectMapper(); // we have a private method in this class
            Order[]  orders = objectMapper.readValue(serverResponseStr, Order[].class);
            if(orders.length>0) {
                return orders[0];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Test class

```
      public class OrdersConnectorImplTest {

        private ObjectMapper mockMapper;

        private class MockOrdersConnectorImpl extends OrdersConnectorImpl {

            @Override
            protected ObjectMapper getObjectMapper() {
                return mockMapper;
            }
        }


    }
      @Test
public void test_getRenewalOrderForContract() throws Exception {
    Response mockResponse = mock(javax.ws.rs.core.Response.class);
    Order mockOrder = mock(Order.class);
    when(mockResponse.getStatusInfo()).thenReturn(Status.OK);
    when(mockResponse.readEntity(String.class)).thenReturn("{}");
    when(mockBuilder.get()).thenReturn(mockResponse);
    when(mockMapper.readValue("{}", Order[].class)).thenReturn(mockOrder); // this is the problem line
    orderConnector.getOrderById("id", OrderType.NEW);

}
}
```

Please correct me here how to return expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have autowired `mockMapper` which means, the actual object of ObjectMapper will be injected.

And in the `when` part, you setting up the behavior of mockMapper, which shouldn't be the case.

**Edit 1**

In your case, there is no need for mocking the Order class, you have to return the array Order which you can create in the tests.
For your information, with Junit there is no way, you can mock the object which is been created inside the method.

Comment: to simply i have added a autowired.. now i have updated the code..  Please let me know how to mock.

Comment: Could you please explain what exactly you are trying to test? which method and stuff like that?

Comment: 1) what is orderServiceTarget?
2) getObjectMapper(); - Does it return new object of ObjectMapper? If that is the case, you cannot mock Object Mapper